# If I have two fields in my form( say Email and Phone number), How to allow user can enter only one value to get into the profile?

Tags: jsp

If I have two fields in my form( say Email and Phone number), How to allow user can enter only one value to access his account?

Comment: I see this is your first Question on Stack Overflow, welcome! Please provide some code so we can see what you have tried and better understand the context of your question, which in turn will help us out to help you. Also see [How To ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask better question which lead to better answers. Note that StackOverflow is not a coding service, we won't work out your assignments.

Comment: Please find the below screenshot for reference